# Delete the pointer allocated for a thread object

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a function which needs to execute some code while the main process runs and I am using a thread like this:

```
void test()
{
     auto& generator = new std::thread(otherFunction, parameters);
}
```

If I try to just call `std::thread(otherFunction, parameters)` instead of allocating it on the heap the process crashes with this error:

```
Debug Error:
Abort() has been called;
```

The same happens when using `std::make_unique` instead of `new`.

How should I manage the deletion of the generator object?

Comment: You can't destroy a thread before it has been joined, which requires that its work has finished. There *is* `detach` but it is basically always an error to use it. Using `new` isn't fixing your problem here, it's hiding it.

Comment: See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Why is it always an error to use detach?

Comment: @Fabrizio It basically indicates that you have given up on properly managing the ownership of the thread. It makes it nearly impossible to cleanly exit from your program or whatever scope your task exists in and complicates managing resources that the thread needs to share, among other problems. A proper design knows who owns which thread, making it significantly easier to write safe and robust code, and easier to reason about the logic of the program.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux So if I understood correctly, If I need the two threads to communicate through a class, it would be a bad idea to detach the thread?

Comment: @Fabrizio Using `detach` won't prevent whatever communication mechanism you choose from working. It just means that your solution is very likely to have problems elsewhere. For example, it may become impossible or very difficult to know when it is safe to dispose of that communication mechanism.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ok Thanks for the explanation!